# Getting the ID from a jQuery Autocomplete UI Box into a form on a JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jquery-ui, jsp, autocomplete

I'm using JSP and jQuery Autocomplete UI.

I'm trying to pass the 'value' of the selected element in my autocomplete box into a form as a hidden value on my JSP.

Here is my script:

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#search").autocomplete({
                source: "list.jsp",
                dataType: "json",
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#userId").val(ui.item.value);                    
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is my form:

```
    <form method="GET" action="view">
        <div class="autocomplete">
            <p>Search: <input id="search"></p>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="<%request.getParameter("userId");%>"/>
    </form>
```

The autocomplete box works great but I can't seem to get a handle on the select element id!

Any help would be greatly appreciated... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solved the issue now.

I should have been using #userId as follows...

```
<input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" />
```

Where **id="userId"** references the #userId.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to set the value of the hidden variable

```
// use <%= %>
   <input type="hidden" name="userId"  value="<%=request.getParameter("userId")%>"/>
```

You have used a scriptlet directly. Probably that is what is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks - that was a problem, but another problem still exists...

I think the 'select' function in the javascript is incorrect...

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Just to clarify, the value is null, not empty.